# NGStyle Changes Not Always Reflected

Tags: angular, ng-style

I have an element that takes ng style but the styles aren't always being applied as expected when the style object changes. I'm specifically refering to the css `animation` below but I've seen similar behavior with `background`.

```html
<div [ngStyle]="_innerStyle">
```

```js
export class WidgetContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  _innerStyle?: {
    [klass: string]: any;
  } | null;
...
}
```

For example `_innerStyle` is

```css
animation: "flash"
animation-duration: "1s"
animation-iteration-count: "infinite"
background-color: "#ffffff"
box-shadow: "0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.12)"
color: "#199719"
```

Result in DOM:

```css
animation: 1s ease 0s infinite normal none running flash;
```

and changes to

```css
animation: "rubberBand"
animation-duration: "1s"
animation-iteration-count: "infinite"
background-color: "#b53b3b"
box-shadow: "0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.12)"
color: "#199719"
```

Result in DOM:

```css
0s ease 0s infinite normal none running flash
```

Why is `animation-duration` being set to `0s` suddenly? I'm printing the JSON object and it does not have `0s` it has `1s`.

Even weirder, if the `animation-duration`'s are different values they get applied correctly on change?! For example: `1s` to `2s` instead of `1s` to `1s`

I expect the dom style to reflect the style object exactly. Am I doing something wrong?! Is there a way to debug ngStyles behavior?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I come to realize `animation` is a shorthand property.
I really wanted to use `animation-name`.

If I were to use `animation` as the css property I would need to build the shorthand value.

By using the individual animation properties the animation is applied correctly and not overwritten by `animation` shorthand property.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be related to change detection where Angular is not kicking in change detection because the reference (location in memory) of `_innerStyle` does not change.

Every time `_innerStyle` changes in your TypeScript/JavaScript, try updating it immutably like so:

```
this._innerStyle = {
   ...this._innerStyle, // keep all of the old properties (spread operator)
  color: 'red',         // change the properties here though
  'background-color': red,
};
```

Comment: You are correct but I was actually already doing exactly this with spread operator. The issue was with my css, see my answer.